# What is $\int\frac{x^2\sec^2 x}{1+x\tan x}\,\text{d}x$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\,\frac{x^2\sec^2 x}{1+x\tan x}\,\text{d}x$$

So, this problem has been disturbing me since a couple of days now. I just can't see it's solution. I tried substituting $\tan x=t$ or $x\tan x= t$ but am just not able to get the answer. Please help. Cheers!!

Comment: Are you sure there are no bounds?

Comment: You have missed the $dx$

Comment: Answer from Wolfy: No result found in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Comment: Is there a mistake?  Did you actually want to find $$\int\,\frac{x^2\,\sec^2(x)}{\big(1+x\,\tan(x)\big)^2}\,\text{d}x\,?$$  If so, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871344/how-to-integrate-this-indefinite-integral.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried? And why would you expect there to be a solution in the first place?

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art, I have posted that I tried to substitute every element I could think of in the question, even the integration of the numerator. Except that, I tried to convert the Trigonometric quantities to $\sin x$ or $\cos x$. But got no luck in any of those. Cheers!!